# Email template pre-wrap not working in Outlook

Tags: email, thymeleaf, html-email

I am rendering a html email template and i have a pre-wrapped text i want to show.

Using `white-space: pre-wrap;` works perfectly everywhere (gmail, yahoo...) except Outlook. I tried using `<pre>/<pre>` this also works perfectly everywhere (gmail, yahoo, even Outlook desktop app), but it doesn't work in Outlook web app.

Any suggestions what should i try next?

Code example 1:

`<td style="color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;">
    <div style="white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: left; font-weight: bold" th:text="${content}"></div>
 </td>`

Code example 2:

`<td style="color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;">
    <pre style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold" th:text="${content}"></pre>
 </td>`

Answer (score 1):

Best way forward probably is then to use Outlook conditional code, i.e.:

```
<td style="color: #153643; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;">
    <!--[if !mso]><!-- --><div style="white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: left; font-weight: bold" th:text="${content}"></div><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if mso]><!-- --><pre style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold" th:text="${content}"></pre><!--<![endif]-->
</td>
```